# Customizing F# QueryBuilder

Tags: f#, query-builder

If I create a customized query builder as in (F# interactive)

```
type T1 = T1 of int list
    with
        member this.Content = let (T1 list) = this in list

type QueryBuilder1() = 
    inherit Linq.QueryBuilder()
        member __.Source (source: T1) = base.Source(source.Content)

let qb1 = new QueryBuilder1()

let list = [1;2;3;4;5]
let t1 = T1 list

let q1 = query { for i in list do select i }
let q2 = query { for i in t1.Content do select i }
let q3 = qb1 { for i in t1 do select i } // OK
```

everything works.

But if I try the same with a SQL database source

```
#r @"C:\Root\Project\Ocnarf\packages\SQLProvider.1.1.44\lib\net451\FSharp.Data.SqlProvider.dll"

let [<Literal>] dbVendor = FSharp.Data.Sql.Common.DatabaseProviderTypes.MSSQLSERVER
let [<Literal>] schemaConnString = @"Data Source=..."
type internal Schema = FSharp.Data.Sql.SqlDataProvider<dbVendor, schemaConnString>
type DowntimeEntity = Schema.dataContext.``dbo.DowntimesEntity``
type DowntimeQuery = System.Linq.IQueryable<DowntimeEntity>

type T2 = T2 of DowntimeQuery
    with
        member this.Query = let (T2 q) = this in q

type QueryBuilder2() = 
    inherit Linq.QueryBuilder()
        member __.Source (source: T2) = base.Source(source.Query)

let db = Schema.GetDataContext()
let tables = db.Dbo
let qry = tables.Downtimes
let t2 = T2 qry
let qb2 = new QueryBuilder2()

let q4 = query { for d in qry do select d }
let q5 = query { for d in t2.Query do select d }
let q6 = qb2 { for d in t2 do select d } // exception
```

then I get the following runtime exception

> System.NotSupportedException: This is not a valid query expression.
>   The method
>   'Microsoft.FSharp.Linq.QuerySource`2[FSharp.Data.Sql.Common.SqlEntity,System.Linq.IQueryable]
>   Source[IQueryable](T2)' was used in a query but is not recognized by
>   the F#-to-LINQ query translator. Check the specification of permitted
>   queries and consider moving some of the operations out of the query
>   expression    at
>   Microsoft.FSharp.Linq.QueryModule.TransInner$cont@1180-3(Boolean
>   check, FSharpExpr immutQuery, Unit unitVar)    at
>   Microsoft.FSharp.Linq.QueryModule.TransInner(CanEliminate canElim,
>   Boolean check, FSharpExpr immutQuery)    at
>   Microsoft.FSharp.Linq.QueryModule.TransInner(CanEliminate canElim,
>   Boolean check, FSharpExpr immutQuery)    at
>   Microsoft.FSharp.Linq.QueryModule.TransInnerApplicative(Boolean check,
>   FSharpExpr source, FSharpVar immutConsumingVar, FSharpExpr
>   immutConsumingExpr)    at
>   Microsoft.FSharp.Linq.QueryModule.TransInner(CanEliminate canElim,
>   Boolean check, FSharpExpr immutQuery)    at
>   Microsoft.FSharp.Linq.QueryModule.TransInnerAndCommit(CanEliminate
>   canElim, Boolean check, FSharpExpr x)    at
>   Microsoft.FSharp.Linq.QueryModule.TransInnerWithFinalConsume(CanEliminate
>   canElim, FSharpExpr immutSource)    at
>   Microsoft.FSharp.Linq.QueryModule.EvalNonNestedInner(CanEliminate
>   canElim, FSharpExpr queryProducingSequence)    at
>   Microsoft.FSharp.Linq.QueryModule.EvalNonNestedOuter(CanEliminate
>   canElim, FSharpExpr tm)    at
>   Microsoft.FSharp.Linq.QueryModule.clo@1727-1.Microsoft-FSharp-Linq-ForwardDeclarations-IQueryMethods-Execute[a,b](FSharpExpr`1
>   q)    at .$FSI_0005.main@()

**QUESTION**

What should I do fix this exception?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the SQL queries are translated from F# quotations to SQL. This is a very sensitive operation and it only works with queries that have the exact format generated by the standard F# query builder. In your case, the constructed query calls your new `Source` method and the translation only recognizes the `Source` method of the base class.

There is no simple easy way to solve this, but you can do a couple of tricks. You can redefine the `Run` method which is called with the created query (F# quotation) and transform the quotation into a form that the F# to SQL translator understands.

In your case, you can replace `<inst>.Source(<arg>)` (your `Source` method) with `<inst>.Source(<arg>.Query)` calling the `Source` method of the base class. The following code does this:

```
open Microsoft.FSharp.Quotations

let rec replace expr = 
  match expr with 
  | Patterns.Call(Some inst, mi, [arg]) when mi.Name = "Source" -> 
      let sourceMethod =
        typeof<Linq.QueryBuilder>.GetMethods() 
        |> Seq.filter (fun mi -> 
             mi.Name = "Source" && 
             mi.GetParameters().[0].ParameterType.Name = "IQueryable`1")
        |> Seq.head
      let sourceMethod = 
        sourceMethod.MakeGenericMethod 
          [| typeof<DowntimeEntity>; typeof<System.Linq.IQueryable> |]
      let queryProp = typeof<T2>.GetProperty("Query")
      Expr.Call(inst, sourceMethod, [ Expr.PropertyGet(arg, queryProp) ])
  | ExprShape.ShapeCombination(o, args) -> 
      ExprShape.RebuildShapeCombination(o, List.map replace args)
  | ExprShape.ShapeLambda(a, b) -> Expr.Lambda(a, replace b)
  | ExprShape.ShapeVar(v) -> Expr.Var(v)

type QueryBuilder2() = 
    inherit Linq.QueryBuilder()
    member __.Source (source: T2) = base.Source(source.Query)
    member __.Run(e:Expr<Linq.QuerySource<'a, System.Linq.IQueryable>>) = 
        let e = Expr.Cast<Linq.QuerySource<'a, System.Linq.IQueryable>>(replace e.Raw)
        base.Run(e)
```

I tested that the translation works, but I have not run this against a real SQL database. The trick is that the `repalce` function is called on the query before it is passed to the F# quotation to SQL translator and in the first case of the pattern matching in `replace`, it does the replacement outlined above.